# Problema con los condicionales

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con este código. Es un juego de pasapalabra. Consiste en adivinar las palabras. Tengo dos botones, uno de validar (valida si la respuesta es correcta o no) y otro que pasa el turno. Al final, cuando vuelve a preguntar las preguntas no contestadas (clicadas con el botón pasapalabra) solo me muestra de nuevo las preguntas que han sido erroneas/acertadas y tendría que mostrarme las que se han pasado palabra. Algo se me está escapando.

esto es mi código:

```js
var questions = [
        { letter: "a", answer: "abducir", status: 0, question: ("CON LA A.") },
        { letter: "b", answer: "bingo", status: 0, question: ("CON LA B.") },
        { letter: "c", answer: "churumbel", status: 0, question: ("CON LA C.") },
        { letter: "d", answer: "diarrea", status: 0, question: ("CON LA D.") },
        { letter: "e", answer: "ectoplasma", status: 0, question: ("CON LA E." ) }
    ]
    
    //Declaro variable que usaremos durante el juego
    var i = 0;
    var success = 0;
    var fail = 0;
    var finalResult;
    
    goToGame.addEventListener('click', printQuestions);
    
    //Función para mostrar las preguntas
    function printQuestions() {
        document.getElementById('game').style.display = 'block';
        
        finalResult = success + fail;
    
        if(finalResult === questions.length) {
            console.log('El juego se ha terminado, has conseguido ' + success + ' aciertos')
        }
        
        if(i === questions.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
    
        if (questions[i].status === 0) {
            document.getElementById('pregunta').innerHTML = questions[i].question;
        }
    
        if (questions[i].status === 1) {
            document.getElementById('pregunta').innerHTML = questions[i].question;
            i++;
            printQuestions();
        }
    }
    
    //Evento para lanzar por click la función que valida
    validateBtn.addEventListener('click', validateAnswer);
    
    //Función para validar si la respuesta es correcta o incorrecta
    function validateAnswer() {
        var bola = 'bola' + i;
        
        if(inputTextGame.value === questions[i].answer) {
            document.getElementById(bola).classList.add('greenBall');
            document.getElementById('inputTextGame').value = '';
            document.getElementById('successCounter').innerHTML = i+1;
            success++;
            i++;
            printQuestions();
        } else {
            document.getElementById(bola).classList.add('redBall');
            document.getElementById('inputTextGame').value = '';
            fail++;
            i++;
            printQuestions();
        }
    }
    
    //Evento para lanzar por click la función que pasa la palabra
    pasapalabraBtn.addEventListener('click', pasapalabra);
    
    //Función para pasar de palabra
    function pasapalabra() {
        questions[i].status = 1;
        var bola = 'bola' + i;
        document.getElementById(bola).classList.add('orangeBall');
        i++;
        console.log('status pregunta' + i + ': ' + questions[i].status)
        printQuestions();
    }
```

```css
* {
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
 background-color: #429DDC;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

#rosco ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #fff;
 color: black;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 25px;
 border: 1px solid #666;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

button {
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding:3px 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

input[type=text] {
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 3px 5px;
}

.btnOrange {
 background-color: orange;
}

#intro {
 display: none;
}

#welcome {
 display: none;
}

#pregunta {
 background-color:#ffcc00;
}

#game {
 display: none;
}


#ranking {
 display: none;
}



.orangeBall {
 background-color: orange !important;
 color: white !important;
}

.redBall {
 background-color: red !important;
 color: white !important;
}

.greenBall {
 background-color: green !important;
 color: white !important; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>PasapalabraJS</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    
     <center>
      <div id="wrapper">
       
       <button id="goToGame">ENTRAR</button>
       
       <!-- bloque pasapalabra -->
       <div id="game">
        <div id="aciertos">
         <p>Aciertos: <span id="successCounter"></span></p>
        </div>
        <div id="cajaPregunta">
         <p id="pregunta"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="rosco">
         <ul>
          <li id="bola0">A</li>
          <li id="bola1">B</li>
          <li id="bola2">C</li>
          <li id="bola3">D</li>
          <li id="bola4">E</li>
         </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="controls">
         <input id="inputTextGame" type="text" placeholder="TU RESPUESTA">
         <button id="validateBtn">Validar</button>
         <button id="pasapalabraBtn">Pasapalabra</button>
         <button id="startGameBtn">Jugar</button>
        </div>
        <p id="textoRanking"></p>
        <button id="startAgain" style="display: none">Jugar de nuevo</button>
       </div>
    
       <!-- bloque ranking + volver a jugar -->
       <div id="ranking">
        <table>
         <tr>
          <td>Ranking de jugadores</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>1er jugador</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>2do jugador</td>
         </tr>
        </table>
        
       </div>
      
      </div>
     </center>
    
     <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/app.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Por favor incluye tambien tu HTML

Comment: tienes razón alanfcm. Incluido

Comment: ahora pueden ejecutar y ver el funcionamiento :D

Comment: genial fredyfx! y ya por pedir... tambien se puede incluir css?

Comment: @jaumeserr claro que puedes incluir css en tu código

Comment: Podrías decirme cómo @the-breaker, me estoy mirando las ayudas y no lo veo... es la primera vez que posteo html+js aquí.

Comment: Coloca _editar_, luego ve debajo del código, debajo del botón _ejecutar_ dice _editar este fragmento de código_, hazle click y te aparecerá un modal en el que puedes colocar html, js y css en 3 espacios, el cuarto es para ver el código ejecutado.

Comment: Mil gracias @the-breaker, ahora es mucho más facil de ver el problema que tengo. A ver si en algún momento alguien me puede hechar un cable.

Comment: creo que te pasa la bola por que igual estas haciendo el incremento de i, quitalo cuando no sea correcto, acabo de hacer la prueba con ese cambio y funciona genial, por favor eliminen los comentarios que no tengan que ver con la pregunta

Comment: si le quito el incremento de i en la validación (cuando es errónea), entonces no corre a la siguiente pregunta @JackNavaRow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas a tomar en cuenta.  Primero, debes de poder distinguir entre la primera vez que iteras las preguntas y las demas iteraciones.  Segundo, debes de tener una manera de saber en donde empezar la siguiente iteracion de las preguntas.  Yo lo resolvi de esta manera:

```js
var questions = [
        { letter: "a", answer: "abducir", status: 0, question: ("CON LA A.") },
        { letter: "b", answer: "bingo", status: 0, question: ("CON LA B.") },
        { letter: "c", answer: "churumbel", status: 0, question: ("CON LA C.") },
        { letter: "d", answer: "diarrea", status: 0, question: ("CON LA D.") },
        { letter: "e", answer: "ectoplasma", status: 0, question: ("CON LA E." ) }
    ]
    
    //Declaro variable que usaremos durante el juego
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var success = 0;
    var fail = 0;
    var finalResult;
    
    goToGame.addEventListener('click', printQuestions);
    
    //Función para mostrar las preguntas
    function printQuestions() {
        document.getElementById('game').style.display = 'block';
        
        finalResult = success + fail;
    
        if(finalResult === questions.length) {
            console.log('El juego se ha terminado, has conseguido ' + success + ' aciertos')
        }
        
        if(i === questions.length) {
           var counter = 0;
            questions.some(function(question) {
              if (question.status === 1) {
                i = counter;
              }
              counter++;
              return question.status === 1
            });
            if(i === questions.length) {
              i = 0;
            }
        }
    
        if (j < 5 && questions[i].status === 0) {
            document.getElementById('pregunta').innerHTML = questions[i].question;
        }
    
        if (questions[i].status === 1) {
            document.getElementById('pregunta').innerHTML = questions[i].question;
            i++;
            j++;
            printQuestions();
        }
    }
    
    //Evento para lanzar por click la función que valida
    validateBtn.addEventListener('click', validateAnswer);
    
    //Función para validar si la respuesta es correcta o incorrecta
    function validateAnswer() {
        var bola = 'bola' + i;
        
        if(inputTextGame.value === questions[i].answer) {
            document.getElementById(bola).classList.add('greenBall');
            document.getElementById('inputTextGame').value = '';
            document.getElementById('successCounter').innerHTML = i+1;
            success++;
            i++;
            j++;
            printQuestions();
        } else {
            document.getElementById(bola).classList.add('redBall');
            document.getElementById('inputTextGame').value = '';
            fail++;
            i++;
            j++;
            printQuestions();
        }
    }
    
    //Evento para lanzar por click la función que pasa la palabra
    pasapalabraBtn.addEventListener('click', pasapalabra);
    
    //Función para pasar de palabra
    function pasapalabra() {
        questions[i].status = 1;
        var bola = 'bola' + i;
        document.getElementById(bola).classList.add('orangeBall');
        console.log('status pregunta' + i + ': ' + questions[i].status)
        i++;
        j++;
        printQuestions();
    }
```

```css
* {
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
 background-color: #429DDC;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

#rosco ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #fff;
 color: black;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 25px;
 border: 1px solid #666;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

button {
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding:3px 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

input[type=text] {
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 3px 5px;
}

.btnOrange {
 background-color: orange;
}

#intro {
 display: none;
}

#welcome {
 display: none;
}

#pregunta {
 background-color:#ffcc00;
}

#game {
 display: none;
}


#ranking {
 display: none;
}



.orangeBall {
 background-color: orange !important;
 color: white !important;
}

.redBall {
 background-color: red !important;
 color: white !important;
}

.greenBall {
 background-color: green !important;
 color: white !important; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>PasapalabraJS</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    
     <center>
      <div id="wrapper">
       
       <button id="goToGame">ENTRAR</button>
       
       <!-- bloque pasapalabra -->
       <div id="game">
        <div id="aciertos">
         <p>Aciertos: <span id="successCounter"></span></p>
        </div>
        <div id="cajaPregunta">
         <p id="pregunta"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="rosco">
         <ul>
          <li id="bola0">A</li>
          <li id="bola1">B</li>
          <li id="bola2">C</li>
          <li id="bola3">D</li>
          <li id="bola4">E</li>
         </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="controls">
         <input id="inputTextGame" type="text" placeholder="TU RESPUESTA">
         <button id="validateBtn">Validar</button>
         <button id="pasapalabraBtn">Pasapalabra</button>
         <button id="startGameBtn">Jugar</button>
        </div>
        <p id="textoRanking"></p>
        <button id="startAgain" style="display: none">Jugar de nuevo</button>
       </div>
    
       <!-- bloque ranking + volver a jugar -->
       <div id="ranking">
        <table>
         <tr>
          <td>Ranking de jugadores</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>1er jugador</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>2do jugador</td>
         </tr>
        </table>
        
       </div>
      
      </div>
     </center>
    
     <script type="text/javascript" src="./app/app.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @alanfcm, diria que soy yo, pero estoy probando el código y cuando le doy al pasapalabra en algún momento y llega al final de la primera "ronda", me salta Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined. Tu código está genial, diria que me falla algo a mi.

Comment: Si @jaumeserr, el error viene de tu codigo original.  Esta en el `console.log()` de tu funcion pasapalabra()

Comment: Algo se me sigue escapando en todo esto. Voy a analizar tu código bien, porque hay cosas que no entiendo. Entiendo que tu lo has testeado y funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias por todo!

Comment: Utilize la variable `var j` para distinguir entre la primera iteracion y las demas.  Tambien utilize `Array.some()` para determinar en donde empezar la siguiente iteracion.  Puedes leer acerca de esta funcion aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: Me informo! Mil gracias de nuevo por la paciencia.